# Run program with database access from Windows Server for concurrent users

Tags: vb.net

My compiled VB.NET program is stored on Windows Server 2016. This program will call a database (.mdb) which is also located on server.

I have created user account with password clients (user) to access and run this program through share folder.

My problem is, this program only can be run by only one user at a time due to database lock for current user. There is any way to make it so that this program can be run by multiple users at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I never heared of Windows Server 2017. Perhaps you mean Sql Server 2017? 
You should/could use a database like SQL Server, Mysql or Postgresql instead of Microsoft Access making multiple user much easier.

See [Is there a downside to using Access as a database?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/221014/is-there-a-downside-to-using-access-as-a-database) for a bit more information.

Comment: @NorhishamYa Note that you may be able to use SQL Server Express, which is free, in case cost could be a problem.

Comment: sorry. its window server 2016